# Android - Cannot retrieve data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am drawing a route between two markers, and I want to save that route. To do that I saved the `ArrayList` containing the lat and lng in the Firebase database. But I am having problems retrieving the waypoints. This is how I inserted:

```
String routeId = database.push().getKey();
database.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").child(routeId).setValue(points);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sh", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("key", routeId);
            editor.commit();
```

Where the `sharedPreferences` string "school" is the name of the school, `routeId` is a `push()` key and the points is an `ArrayList` of waypoints.

My database:

[image: database structure]

My POJO classes:

```
public static class Route {

    private ArrayList<Location> locations;

    public Route() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(ArrayList<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}


public static class Location {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Retrieval of waypoints:

```
  points = new ArrayList();
    userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").child(sh.getString("key",null)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
            for (Location location : route.getLocations()) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
        }
```

But I am getting a database exception:

> DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type packagename

I don't know why.

Comment: see this :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933328/how-to-convert-firebase-data-to-java-object

Comment: I tried using the getAllChildren method like shown in your link, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, but I think it's the saving of the data that's letting it down. When you load the data back from the database you're marshalling the data into a `Route` instance:

```
Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
```

This will expect a `locations` node under each child to match `setLocations(ArrayList<Location>)` in your POJO class. Instead, the data it retrieves is the `ArrayList` directly.

When saving your location list, you'll need to arrange the structure such that the list of locations are stored under `$schoolName/routes/$routeId/locations`:

[image: database structure]

So, when saving your route point data, you'll need to do:

```
database.child(schoolName).child("routes").child(routeId).child("locations").setValue(points);
```

An easy way to think of this would be: if the `Route` also had a name field (`setName(String)`) then the database may also have `$schoolName/routes/$routeId/name` in the same place as the `locations` value.

Alternatively, when saving to the database, you could convert your `points` variable to a `Route` instance and then push that directly to `$schoolName/routes/$routeId` instead, which will ensure that it's stored correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I go by your second solution: The `points` variable is an arraylist. Is there a simple way to convert it to a `Route` instance?

Comment: Is the `points` variable already an `ArrayList<Location>`? You could just do `Route route = new Route(); route.setLocations(points);` or create a constructor for it.

Comment: Quick question: The code that is running inside `onDataChange`, will that only take the last added waypoints?

Comment: It will iterate through each child that has been pushed to the `routes` node. If you only want the latest, you'll need to use a query to [sort and filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) them: you can append `orderByKey()` and `limitToLast(1)` to your reference to only obtain the most recent.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking more of the opposite, so that I can draw as many polylines as childs in the 'routes' node. I will try to figure it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    final HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,Double>> positions = new HashMap<>();
    userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").child(sh.getString("key",null)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i=0;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                HashMap<String,Double> position = new HashMap<String, Double>();
                position.put("lat",Double.parseDouble(postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString()));
                position.put("lng",Double.parseDouble(postSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString()));
                positions.put(i++,position);
            }

        }
```

You can access the values stored in `positions` variable as

```
 positions.get(index).get("lat");
 positions.get(index).get("lng");
```

Comment: NumberFormatException: For input string: "DataSnapshot { key = lat, value = null

Comment: I tried this also. I got the same error as before: DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type packagename

Comment: @JDoe  Wait i know what the error is. I'll update the code

Comment: I get this error now: NumberFormatException: For input string: "DataSnapshot { key = latitude, value = 55.3975 }